# Breaking the reference between two objects

Tags: ruby

I've been struggling for hours.

I am trying to break the link between two objects so I can edit one without affecting the other, but `dup` does not work at all.

When I try to `dup` a Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet, it gives me an object with a different `object_id` than the original, but when I modify the copy, it affects the nodes in the original! Is there any way in Ruby to break the link between the two objects?

```
def copy(collection)
  body = @doc.xpath("//w:body")
  children = @doc.xpath("//w:body").children
  body.children.map(&:remove)

  collection.each do |record|

    puts "it appears child is forever affected #{children}"
    clone = children.dup

    clone = Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet.new(@doc, clone)
    parse_nodes clone, record
    body.first << clone.to_xml
  end
end
```

Comment: I think I found the solution. I will post it shortly. The solution is to convert to_xml and then use parse to parse it back into a nodeset. I am testing to see if it works at this moment.

Comment: I also deleted my other question regarding the recursive function, because the problem wasn't recursion. It was referenced values.

Comment: Your issue is not that `dup` is not working. It is that `dup` works on the outer object. So `dup`ing a `NodeSet` will create a new `NodeSet` but the nodes inside are the same referenced nodes. This is why Rails and many other interfaces have added a `deep_dup` method.

Comment: Expanding on what @engineersmnky said, the reason that using `to_xml` works, is it serializes the entire document, allowing Nokogiri to totally reparse it and generate a new DOM, which will have absolutely no references to the original DOM. This is similar to using Ruby's Marshall class to do a "deep dup".

Comment: I try deep_dup on node set. it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating your own `NodeSet` like this

```
dup_node_set = Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet.new(@doc, children.to_a.map(&:dup))
```

Not sure if that will run deep enough for you although since your method is recursive I would assume it should.

What this is doing is converting the `children` `NodeSet` to an `Array` and then calling `dup` on each `element` inside and passing this to a new `NodeSet`.